# Selecting and displaying an image during runtime in a windows app created using MFC

Tags: mfc

I'm creating an Windows app with `MFC` where user can click a `Add Photo` button. Then select an image file From the `CFileDialog` which pops up.  And the picture selected is then dispalyed in the picture box in my main window.

Can somebody please help me to know how to achieve this. I am a newbie and any kind of help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Search the web for tutorials on how to display an image in MFC picture box and how to open CFileDialog. Should be plenty of stuff available

Answer (score 0):

Please read documentary to this:
You need CFileDialog for image selection,
Member variable to a Cpicturecontrol with type of Bitmap, a Cstring for the path and a CImage variable.
Take the selected path to the string variable mypath
Then do 
myimage.Load(mypath);
mypicture.SetBitmap(myimage.Detach());